# Monthly subscription using IAP

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

We are planning to develop an iPhone application in which, one of our
requirement is that we want to collect the fees through the application
monthly. We wish to achieve this through in-app purchase.
Is this possible in iPhone application using IAP? If Yes, then will you
please guide us.
Is this kind of app will be approved while submitting to iTunes Store?

Comment: I remember hearing that you can only charge a monthly fee if you are delivering new content on a monthly basis (like a magazine subscription)....

Comment: We will not be delivering any new content, we will only take fee for access of the services, will it be allowed by Apple to charge monthly without providing new content in the app itself

Answer (score 1):

You can do implement it using Auto-Renewable Subscriptions.Here are the docs
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html

If you don't want to dive in too deeply into this, you can use MKStoreKit, it also supports Auto-Renewables.It just makes your life easier.

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/mkstorekit-4-0-supporting-auto-renewable-subscriptions/

Comment: We want to know whether we can integrate IAP monthly subscription without providing any digital media in the app.

Comment: You really provide nothing at all?

Comment: We will provide suggestions in textual form only.

Comment: I think, that it's digital content anyway,si you could try